# Graphite - offset series by standard deviation of itself

Tags: graphite, grafana

I'm using Graphite and Grafana and I'm trying to plot a series against a time shifted version of itself for comparison.

(I.e. is the current value similar to this time last week?)

What I'd like to do is plot;

1. the 5 minute moving average of the series
2. a band consisting of the 5 minute moving average of the series timeshifted by 7 days, bounded above and below by the standard deviation of itself

That way I can see if the current moving average falls within a band limited by the standard deviation of the moving average from a week ago.

I have managed to produce a band based on the timeshifted moving average, but only by offsetting either side by a constant amount. I can't work out any way of offsetting by the standard deviation (or indeed by any dynamic value).

I've copied a screenshot of the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve. The yellow line is the current moving average, the green area is bounded by the historical moving average offset either side by the standard deviation.

Is this possible at all in Grafana using Graphite as the backend?

I'm not quite on the latest version, but can easily upgrade (and will do so shortly anyway).

Incidentally, I'm not a statistician, if what I'm doing actually makes no sense mathematically, I'd love to know! ;-) My overall goal is to explore better alternatives, instead of using static thresholds, for highlighting anomalous or problematic server performance metrics - e.g. CPU load, disk IOPS, etc.

[image: Example of moving average inside static offset]